# How do I get this Selection Search to work?

Tags: c++

I am trying sort the ten values in an array in descending order but I can't seem to get it right.

I've tried copying the code in my book twice, I even copied a code from youtube but it still didn't work. Someone please help me! I've tried everything and it's freaking me out.

```
void selectionSort(int list[], int size)
{
  //Display variables
  int minIndex, minValue, num;

  //Calculate the array in descending order
  for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
  {

    minValue = list[index];
    minIndex = index;

    for(int index2; index2 < size; index2++)
    {
        if(list[index2] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = list[index2];
            minIndex = index2;
        }
    }
    swap(list[index], list[minIndex]); //function call
  }

  //Display the array in descending order
  cout<<"The scores in descending order are ";

  for(int num = 0; num < size; num++)
  {
    cout<<list[num]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
```

When I run the program the algorithm doesn't sort anything it displays the same exact array with no change.

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo in your book – you don't initialise `index2`.

Comment: `for(int index2 = index+1; index2 < size; index2++)`

Comment: Changed it but I still got the same results.

Comment: @KoolKassia may be you defined your own _swap_ doing in fact nothing ? (I edited my answer)

Comment: The problem *might* be that your function [sorts in *ascending* order](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3f50a4e0abd41f2), so if you give it an ascending array (after fixing the indexing bug), you will not see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

in *selectionSort*

> ```
> for(int index2 ; index2 < size; index2++)
> ```

must be

```
for(int index2 = index+1; index2 < size; index2++)
```

else it is not initialized and the behavior is undefined when using it as an index for *list*.

After that :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void selectionSort(int list[], int size)
{
  //Display variables
  int minIndex, minValue, num;

  //Calculate the array in descending order
  for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
  {

    minValue = list[index];
    minIndex = index;

    for(int index2 = index+1; index2 < size; index2++)
    {
        if(list[index2] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = list[index2];
            minIndex = index2;
        }
    }
    swap(list[index], list[minIndex]); //function call
  }

  //Display the array in descending order
  cout<<"The scores in descending order are ";

  for(int num = 0; num < size; num++)
  {
    cout<<list[num]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  int v[] = { 1,8,6,9,0,2,3};

  selectionSort(v, (int) (sizeof(v)/sizeof(int)));
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
c.cc: In function ‘void selectionSort(int*, int)’:
c.cc:7:27: warning: unused variable ‘num’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int minIndex, minValue, num;
                           ^~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
The scores in descending order are 0 1 2 3 6 8 9
```

As the compiler says the first *num* can be removed, or do not redefine it in *for*

---

> When I run the program the algorithm doesn't sort anything it displays the same exact array with no change.

and your remark after the correction above :

> Changed it but I still got the same results.

A probable cause is you defined your own *swap* with a definition doing *nothing* like that :

```
void swap(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a;

    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

rather than for instance

```
void swap(int & a, int & b)
{
    int c = a;

    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

or using a template of course